# Creating installation files depended on NuGet packages doesn’t work in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, installation, nuget-package

Is it possible to get pug in project for Outlook that is depend on NuGet packages to be installed with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects? I’m trying to create an installation file for a plug in for Outlook that have a drag and drop functionality dependent on the Easyhook Nuget package. That the plugin have a taskPane with a webbrowser there are drop Outlook e-mail messages as .msg files.

It works to install the plug in but the drag and drop functionality that is dependent on the NuGet package doesn’t work. That I can drop the message but the webpage doesn’t recognize the drop mails as .msg files or even as uploadable files. While if I try with the trial version of InstallShield 2018 Express Edition everything works including the drag and drop functionality.
I tried to do the same thing with Installer Project as with InstallShield. To output I added content files, debug symbols and primary output. Files I added was the manifest and vsto files for the Plugin and the .dll file for the NuGet Package, Easyhook32.dll. I got an error because the content file included the 64bit for the NuGet Package files, and I’m doing a 32bit installation, and also that the Easyhook32.dll file was duplicate, that it seems that the dll file also was added with the content files.

So, I excluded the 64bit files in the plug In project that should be installed and in the installation project I removed Easyhook32.dll files from the files that should be include in the installation. Also then it worked to install the plugin but the drag and drop functionality didn’t work. I also tried to for example not add the content files and just add the Easyhook32.dll and that also made the installation work except the drag and drop functionality.

I can of course also try other installation programs that is able to add NuGet but also are able to be installed from the Internet and also add registry keys and values. That I also have tried Microsoft Click Once installations program and it was easy to create an installation files but it seems like you need a valid certification if you want users to download the installation file from the Internet.

Also, this is the first time I working with type of installation like this ones and with Outlook Add In so I can have missed some obvious solutions. That at the same time english is not my first language so I can also have missed using the correct terminology.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet is a build-time package manager. You'll need to redistribute any required binaries in your installer package by adding them manually. Typically, required binaries from NuGet packages will be copied to your output folder, so you could add them from those paths just like your project output.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I can only find one binary file for Easyhook in the output, Easyhook.dll. The file is automatically added to detected dependency for the installation package. I now tried to exclude the file and instead added it manually to the installation, but it didn’t work either. After that I tried other things like also adding the Easyhook.xml file in the output and also adding a EasyHook32Svc.exe file and Easyload32.dll file that was in the main folder of the project that should be installed. That I just wanted to try everything.